# Shapefiles to Adjust Hawaii and Alaska

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Does anyone know if there is a shapefile available which moves Alaska and Hawaii closer to the continental USA?

I have attached a photo which might help.

[image]

Comment: Any shapefile which has Alaska and Hawaii out of their true location would be incorrect. If you simply want to display them in that position, you can add separate map frames in the print composer to achieve the same visual effect.

Comment: If you have a U.S. County map, from Census.gov for example, you can edit the location of Alaska and Hawaii quite easily.

Comment: You are trying to do an inset map.

Comment: You will need a different scale for your inset map of Alaska because Alaska is over twice the size of a Texas! http://www.alaska.org/how-big-is-alaska